# How to decode JWT of STIR/SHAKEN into JSON object?

Tags: c#, jwt, x509, ecdsa

I am trying to decode a STIR/SHAKEN HS256 JSON Web Token.

I tried with the Jose .NET library:

```
string token = "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInBwdCI6InNoYWtlbiIsInR5cCI6InBhc3Nwb3J0IiwieDV1IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jci5zYW5zYXkuY29tL1RlY2hub2xvZ3lfSW5ub3ZhdGlvbl9MYWJfNTk5SiJ9.eyJhdHRlc3QiOiJCIiwiZGVzdCI6eyJ0biI6WyIxNDc5MjM5OTcwMyJdfSwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NTIxNDU5LCJvcmlnIjp7InRuIjoiMTQ2OTUwMTYwNzAifSwib3JpZ2lkIjoiOTIzNDIxOTgtMTMxNC0xMWVkLWExM2QtYmRjMWMxZDI4ODg4In0.8RF_eaVKeGGyjet4lujwPz0J_XBdtwkSKrnrOq7-pA6ODtJPD1parLgimEpDUyzSravtTaxuACxBz4yrKtMZgw";
  
string x = Jose.JWT.Decode(token, Nothing, JweAlgorithm.PBES2_HS256_A128KW);
```

It gives an error

> Jose.InvalidAlgorithmException: 'The algorithm type passed to the Decode method did not match the algorithm type in the header.'

Trying the token above on https://jwt.io/ Debugger works and returns the following:

HEADER:ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

```
{
  "alg": "ES256",
  "ppt": "shaken",
  "typ": "passport",
  "x5u": "https://cr.sansay.com/Technology_Innovation_Lab_599J"
}
```

PAYLOAD:DATA

```
{
  "attest": "B",
  "dest": {
    "tn": [
      "14792399703"
    ]
  },
  "iat": 1659521459,
  "orig": {
    "tn": "14695016070"
  },
  "origid": "92342198-1314-11ed-a13d-bdc1c1d28888"
}
```

Comment: That's not HS256, that's ES256.

Comment: so `JwsAlgorithm.ES256` should be the right algo, but then you also need the public key, you can't just pass `Nothing`. But actually you need the key and algo to verify the signature, decoding is trivial as you have seen on jwt.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token is actually signed with the ES256 algorithm, not HS256.
The public key certificate is provided in the URL that is given in the header in the [`X5U`-claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515#section-4.1.5), which is a URL pointing to a X.509 certificate.
For the demo below and to keep it simple, I saved the certificate to a file name `x509.pem`.

Here is a simple demo (based on the [examples](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt#verifying-and-decoding-tokens) in the [Jose-JWT](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) GitHub repo:

```
using Jose;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace JoseJWTES256X509Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string token = "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInBwdCI6InNoYWtlbiIsInR5cCI6InBhc3Nwb3J0IiwieDV1IjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jci5zYW5zYXkuY29tL1RlY2hub2xvZ3lfSW5ub3ZhdGlvbl9MYWJfNTk5SiJ9.eyJhdHRlc3QiOiJCIiwiZGVzdCI6eyJ0biI6WyIxNDc5MjM5OTcwMyJdfSwiaWF0IjoxNjU5NTIxNDU5LCJvcmlnIjp7InRuIjoiMTQ2OTUwMTYwNzAifSwib3JpZ2lkIjoiOTIzNDIxOTgtMTMxNC0xMWVkLWExM2QtYmRjMWMxZDI4ODg4In0.8RF_eaVKeGGyjet4lujwPz0J_XBdtwkSKrnrOq7-pA6ODtJPD1parLgimEpDUyzSravtTaxuACxBz4yrKtMZgw";
            var publicKey = new X509Certificate2("x509.pem").GetECDsaPublicKey();

            string payload = Jose.JWT.Decode(token, publicKey, JwsAlgorithm.ES256);

            Console.WriteLine(payload);
        }
    }
}
```

As a result the token will be verified and the payload will be printed. In case of a failed verification, the `Decode`-function would throw an exception.

As a side note: the `Decode`-function actually verifies the signature before decoding, and that's for what it needs the key. For the actual decoding, no key is needed because the payload is just Base64Url encoded. That's why https://jwt.io can also decode the token without knowing the key.